# iPhone: initWithContentURL not playing the video

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I have a .mp4 video url in my server and trying to play by using the following code. But it doesn't do any actions when click on play button. I'm trying to test on iPhone 4.0 simulator or iPod 4.1 device. Is there anything wrong here (or) can't it work on iOS 4.0 or 4.1?

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:encodedURL];
MPMoviePlayerController *videoPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];
[self.view addSubview:videoPlayer.view];
videoPlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
[videoPlayer play];
```

Please advise!

Encode function:

```
NSString *newString = [(NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)string, NULL, CFSTR("?#[]@!$ &'()*+,;=\"<>%{}|^~`"), CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)) autorelease];
```

Comment: Can you show us how you create encodedURL and include the link to the mp4 (if it is not private). Some formats cannot be played.

Comment: I added my encoded string function used in my question above..The link is playing on iPhone 4 simulator Safari browser.

Comment: (CFStringRef)string : Can you show its value?

Comment: See my answer below and also you should be using http:// at the front since it is a remote file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file is on a server than the line:

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:encodedURL];

should be:

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:encodedURL];

You should also double check that the string encodedURL is correct by NSlog to your console.